# python looping in list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

need some help on looping the all the list and print the list name
currently i have few raspberry pi type and windows PC, i want to ping all the pi and windows and get respond
below are some of what i have tried

question is how to loop, piserver, pi2b,pi2,pi3,pi4 and windows

```
import platform
plat = platform.system()
piservers = {"10.10.10.115", "10.10.10.125", "10.10.10.135", "10.10.10.145", "10.10.10.165", "10.10.10.175", "10.10.10.185"}
pi2b= {"10.10.10.111", "10.10.10.112", "10.10.10.113", "10.10.10.114"}
pi2 = {"10.10.10.121", "10.10.10.122", "10.10.10.123", "10.10.10.124"}
pi3 = {"10.10.10.131", "10.10.10.132", "10.10.10.133", "10.10.10.134"}
pi4 = {"10.10.10.141", "10.10.10.142", "10.10.10.143", "10.10.10.144"}
Windows = {"10.10.10.151", "10.10.10.152", "10.10.10.153", "10.10.10.154"}

for vm in piservers :
    # Check for Windows and Linux Platforms
    if plat == "Windows":
        response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + vm)
        pass

    elif plat == "Linux":
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 -W 3 " + vm)
        pass

    #and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        print ("***********************************")
        print(vm, 'is UP!')
        print ("***********************************")
        print ("\n")
    elif response == 2 or 256 or 512:
        print ("***********************************")
        print(vm, 'is DOWN and No response from Server!')
        print ("***********************************")
        print ("\n")
    else:
        print ("***********************************")
        print(vm, 'is DOWN!')
        print ("***********************************")
        print ("\n")
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include an actual question, and a description of the problems you have with the code you show.

Comment: I think you want to redirect output of os.system().and want to check the ping response...

Comment: I don't understand what the *question* is, but I can tell you that `response == 2 or 256 or 512` does not mean what you expect it to mean.

Comment: I also recommend that you do some research about [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

Comment: Your Elif statement is not correct. Either do `elif response in [2, 256, 512]:` or  `elif response == 2 or response == 256 or response == 512:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through all the sets at once, you can do:

```
for vm in piservers|pi2b|pi2|pi3|pi4|Windows:
```

**Update**

To get the server list name, write a function like this:

```
def get_server(ip):
    servers = ['piservers', 'pi2b', 'pi2', 'pi3', 'pi4', 'Windows']
    for server in servers:
        if ip in eval(server):
            return server
    return ''
```

Use this function where ever you need to show the list name.
for example:

```
get_server('10.10.10.151')                                                                                                           
'Windows'
get_server('10.10.10.133')                                                                                                           
'pi3'
```

In your case, the code will look like this,

```
get_server(vm)
```

Comment: thank you, how to print the list name if its fail ?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement? @AjwadIbrahim

Comment: form above code, you can get output of UP and DOWN, depends on the ping, what i want to do is, let say one of the ping from list "pi2" is DOWN, how do i print the Name of the list and says one of the system is DOWN in "pi2"

Comment: @AjwadIbrahim Please see the updated answer. Use the given function to get the list name. Let me know if you face any issues. Please do upvote the answer if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your `elif` statement, it should be:

```
elif response == 2 or response == 256 or response == 512:
```